# How can i detect a jquery click on a div that is on a content using master page?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, infragistics

so i have recently start working with asp.net and c#, i am trying to do a day scheduler, and when i created the sheduler on a simple page, without using master page , it was working fine, now i am trying to create the same page but using master page.

I have been searching for aswers and i thing that the problem is related with de master page id is connect with the ids from the content.
here is my code.
What i have is a master page and on the content ive got a infragistics control called webdatagrid, in the grid i have a column id, and a column with a component inside...
the code for the component is below:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Segmentos.ascx.cs" Inherits="IdOntime.Segmentos" %>
<style type="text/css">
.divttt
{
background-color:#fff;
width:30px;height:32px;
float:left;
border-bottom:solid 1px #000;
border-top:solid 1px #000;
border-left:solid 1px #000
}
</style>

 <div  class="divttt">
 </div>
 <div class="divttt">
 </div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt">
</div>
<div class="divttt" style="  border-right:solid 1px #000">

</div>
```

Basiccally is 24divs on a row...and when i clicked in one the color goes for black or whit depending the current color.

code for Webform5.aspx

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm5.aspx.cs" Inherits="IdOntime.WebForm5" %>
<%@ Register src="~/Segmentos.ascx" tagname="Segmento" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.20111.1006, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls" TagPrefix="ig" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js">     </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
       <script  type="text/javascript">
           $(function() {
               var hi;
               var qt;
               var rows;
               var horas = [];
               var qthoras = [];
               var qt = 0;
               var todo = 0;
               var show = 0;
               var columns, alldivs;
               var iduser, row, divshorario, teste, grid, rows;

               $("#Button1").click(function(evt) {
                   evt.preventDefault();
                   grid = $find('<%= this.WebDataGrid1.ClientID %>');
                   rows = grid.get_rows();
                   //alert("rows lenght:" + rows.get_length());
                   for (i = 0; i < rows.get_length(); i++) {
                       //alert(i);
                       row = rows.get_row(i)
                       iduser = row.get_cell(0).get_text();
                       divshorario = row.get_cell(1).get_text();
                       teste = row.get_cell(1).get_text();
                       //alert(teste);

                       alldivs = $(divshorario).filter('.divttt');
                       var elementsLength = alldivs.length;


                       $.each(alldivs, function(j, l) {
                           //alert(j);
                           var x = $(l).css('backgroundColor');
                           if (x == 'black') {
                               if (todo == 0) {
                                   alert("k:" + j);
                                   hi = j;
                                   todo = 1;
                                   show = 0;
                               }
                               qt++;
                           }
                           else {
                               if (show == 0 && todo == 1) {
                                   alert("valor da hora inicial:" + (hi) + " e a hora final:" + (j));
                                   $.ajax({
                                       type: "POST",
                                       url: "WebForm5.aspx/DeleteUploadedFile",
                                       data: "{ID: '" + iduser+ "', horai:'"+hi+"' , horaf:'"+j+"'}",
                                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                       dataType: "json",
                                       success: function(msg) {

                                       },
                                       error: function(response) {


                                       }
                                   });
                                   show = 1;
                               }
                               todo = 0;
                               qt = 0;
                           }

                       });


                       show = 0;

                   }






               });


           });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var myArray = [];

 $(window).load(function() {

     var mousedown = false;
     var bid, bid2;
     var trid, trid2;
     var color;
     var row;


     trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
     row = $('#' + trid);



     $(document).mousedown(function() { mousedown = true; });
     $(document).mouseup(function() { mousedown = false; });

     $('div.divttt').mousedown(function() {

         //bid = this.id; // button ID
         //trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // table row ID
         trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

         //alert(trid);
         myArray.push(trid);
         var b = $(this).css("background-color");
         // alert(b);
         if (b == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {
             $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'black');
             color = 'black';
             // alert("branco");
         }

         else if (b == 'rgb(222, 222, 222)') {
             //alert('cinza');
             $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#DEDEDE');
             ///alert("teste");

         }
         else {

             $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'white');
             color = 'white';
         }
     });

     $('div.divttt').mouseover(function() {

         if (mousedown) {
             // var b = $(this).css("background-color");
             // alert(b);
             // bid2 = this.id; // button ID
             trid2 = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // table row ID
             //alert(trid2+"||"+trid);
             if (trid2 == trid) {
                 $(this).css('backgroundColor', color);
             }


         }

     });
 }); 

</script>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#WebDataGrid1
{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
<ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGrid1"  runat="server" Height="350px" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="ID" Key="ID" Width="50px">
            <Header Text="ID" />
        </ig:BoundDataField>

        <ig:TemplateDataField Key="Segmentos" Width="745px">
        <Header Text="Segmentos" />
        <ItemTemplate>

            <uc1:Segmento ID="Segmento1" runat="server"></uc1:Segmento>
        </ItemTemplate>

        </ig:TemplateDataField>

    </Columns>
</ig:WebDataGrid>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Button" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

in the master page master1.page ive declared this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function() {

     var mousedown = false;
     var bid, bid2;
     var trid, trid2;
     var color;
     var row;


     $(document).mousedown(function() { mousedown = true; });
     $(document).mouseup(function() { mousedown = false; });

     $('div.divttt').mousedown(function() {

         //bid = this.id; // button ID
         //trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // table row ID
         trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

         alert(trid);
     });
 };
 </script>
 ...
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server">
                                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 ...
```

in the page asHorariosEscalas.aspx i've got this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AsHorariosEscalas.aspx.cs" Inherits="IdOntime.asHorariosEscalas" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="Site1.master" %>
<%@ Register src="~/Segmentos.ascx" tagname="Segmento" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="SelPessoas.ascx" TagName="SelPessoas" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.20111.1006, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls" TagPrefix="ig" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.20111.1006, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.Web.UI.ListControls" TagPrefix="ig" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.WebDataInput.v11.1, Version=11.1.20111.1006, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.WebUI.WebDataInput" TagPrefix="igtxt" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.20111.1006, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.Web.UI.NavigationControls" TagPrefix="ig" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.20111.1006, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.Web.UI.EditorControls" TagPrefix="ig" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.WebDataInput.v11.1, Version=11.1.20111.1006, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.WebUI.WebDataInput" TagPrefix="igtxt" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v11.1, Version=11.1.20111.1006, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid" TagPrefix="igtbl" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebNavigator.v11.1, Version=11.1.20111.1006, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebNavigator" TagPrefix="ignav" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Infragistics2.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.20111.1006, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"
Namespace="Infragistics.Web.UI.LayoutControls" TagPrefix="ig" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="cphMain"  >

<div  runat="server" style="    
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;">


<ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGridPlaneamentoHorarios"  runat="server" Height="400px" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="1000px"  >
    <Columns>
        <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="ID" Key="ID" Width="50px" >
            <Header Text="ID" />
        </ig:BoundDataField>


        <ig:TemplateDataField Key="Segmentos" Width="745px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <uc1:Segmento ID="Segmento1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <Header Text="Segmentos" />
        </ig:TemplateDataField>

    </Columns>
</ig:WebDataGrid>
  <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphSidebar">
<br />
<br />
<uc1:SelPessoas ID="SelPessoas1" runat="server" />
<br />
<br />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content5" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMenuOptions">
<ig:WebDataMenu ID="WebDataMenuOptions" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" OnItemClick="WebDataMenuOptions_ItemClick">
    <ItemSettings />
    <Items>
        <ig:DataMenuItem ImageUrl="~/img/refresh_16.png" Key="btnRefrescar" Text="Refrescar">
        </ig:DataMenuItem>
    </Items>
    <GroupSettings Orientation="Horizontal" />
</ig:WebDataMenu>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add an onclick event programatically on the content page, that way it will attach to everything that has been loaded on from the master page as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.divttt').on('click','alert("clicked!")');
});
```